Spring Cloud Data Flow - Passing secret to the Cloud Task
How to pass the secrets to a cloud task when executing through Spring Cloud Data Flow. I am trying to set the secrets using deployer properties but it's not working
Thanks for your help in advance.
spring.cloud.deployer.<<app-name>>.kubernetes.secretRefs: ref-app-secret
I have tried the above configuration in the spring cloud data flow server application.yml but no luck

When you configure properties in Spring Cloud Data Flow you have deployer properties and application properties.
You will have to decided if the property needs to end update as an application property or if it is used by the relevant deployer when deploying the application.
The are configured as follows:

application.<app-name>.property-key=value
deployer.<app-name>.property-key=value

Deployer properties required for all tasks or streams can be configured on Data Flow Server or the Skipper Server. https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-kubernetes
The specifics about sending a secretKeyRef as environmental variable to a task or stream is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_secret_key_references
